# How to calculate pitch, yaw and roll using two sets of 3d points?

Tags: rotations, orientation

I am trying to calculate the pitch, yaw and roll of the forearm using two sets of two 3d(x,y,z) coordinates during movement, a set for the wrist and a set for the elbow. **I would like to know how to calculate pitch, yaw and roll angles from these two coordinate sets? The order of the rotations is not important, they can be treated as individual rotations.**

I have seen that the roll cannot be calculated with two points alone. **If this is the case, how can I calculate roll, presumably using three points?** **Also why can roll not be calculated with only two points?**

The rotations are required to work out maximum and minimum joint angles.

Any help with this could be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that a rotation $R$ is not uniquely determined from knowing that  $R(\vec{u})=\vec{v}$ for a pair of (unit) vectors $\vec{u}$, $\vec{v}$. Here $\vec{u}$  is a reference vector, like the on pointing in the direction of the $x$-axes, and $\vec{v}$ is the vector from the elbow to the wrist. The non-uniqueness shows as follows. If $R'$ is any rotation about the vector $\vec{u}$ and $R''$ is any rotation about the vector $\vec{v}$, then, instead of $R$, the rotation $R\circ R'$ as well as the rotation $R''\circ R$ both take $\vec{u}$ to $\vec{v}$.

Comment: (cont'd) We could also do $R''\circ R\circ R'$, but that won't produce any more *distinct* rotations. Presumably *roll* is either $R''$ or $R'$, but I have no clue which, because you didn't give a definition (or the order in which the three basic rotations are to be carried out). And, the relation of pitch/roll/yaw to a general rotation has been discussed in dozens of threads on this site. Did you search? Start from the list of *Related* questions in the right margin.

Comment: My question was perhaps not clear enough, the rotations are not together. For example, only raw angle, only pitch angle, only roll angle.

Comment: What I don't understand is why are these two points (elbow and wrist) are supposed to be related by a rotation, rather than a translation?  What is the axis of rotation ?  Your question has gaps in it.

Comment: The elbow and wrist coordinates are two sets of keypoints, tracking the elbow and wrist during a movement. I have updated the question

Comment: (cont'd) The rotations are required to work out maximum and minimum joint angles.

Comment: How many 3D points do you have at each location (elbow and wrist). I assume that this is from a motion capture system.  Seems like they would have done that processing.

Comment: @tpofofn There is a single point in 3d space for each joint. tracked over time. I am using a kinect :)

Comment: Then you will not be able to get a full roll, pitch, and yaw rotation.  The best you can do would be yaw and pitch (i.e. spherical coordinates) .

Comment: Thank you @Tpofofn . What then is the minimum number of points required to calculate roll for a segment e.g. forearm? Would it require just one additional point on the segment that is non colinear?

Comment: In general to compute the roll pitch and yaw you need three non-colinear 3D points on the forearm.

Comment: If the kinect also tracks the position of the shoulder and of the hand you might be able to get it from there.